# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi not working after update

Tags: 16.04, broadcom

I'm using following wifi hardware (08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01))

```
network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c1500000-c1507fff
```

This has just stopped working after recent update by Ubuntu which made me auto remove few files as they weren't needed.

I have tried following links none worked:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
https://grenangen.se/node/86

Kindly help

Sicerely

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Answer (score 3):

Like @Juxmix said, I disabled the **proprietary driver**, restarted and it didn't work. Then I executed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and it worked.

EDIT:
The wifi with the b43 firmware was running a little bit slower then Broadcom one.

1. disable the networking
2. uinstall the b43 drivers

   sudo apt remove firmware-b43-installer
3. follow the instructions on this [link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/15855/15147)

Comment: i already have its newest version :(

Comment: Did you disable the proprietary driver?

Comment: Yup I have disabled it and uninstalled it as well

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Wireless card and have faced similar issue immediately after installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Please go to 'Additional Drivers' tab in 'Softwares & Updates'. Check if your wireless card is listed and ensure that it is using the **proprietary** drivers from Broadcom.

[image]

If the device is not listed or driver is not found, connect your system to Internet using a **wired connection** and install all updates using 'software updater'.

Run `sudo apt-get update` to refresh all the repositories.

For me, automatically found the proper drivers and the Wi-Fi started working after a restart.
Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for your comment but the device is listed and with update i meant recent updates issued by ubuntu16.04

Comment: So even with proprietary driver it's not working?

Comment: yup it isn't working

Comment: ohh ok. Lots of people with this WiFi card are facing this issue after yesterday's update.

Comment: I have tried almost everything seems like there is no new post regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same network controller, after updating. Tried winding back to an earlier version, network restart... Nothing worked.

What worked uninstalling "our" 16.04 version of the broadcom drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then installing the 18.04 binaries which can be found here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bcmwl-kernel-source

With this command or simply opening the file with the software center.

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

The original source, from another part of Stackexchange can be found following this link:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/bcm43142-and-linux-kernel-4-15-0-24-generic

Comment: the second command is not working on ubuntu16.04 and I don't know how to download the package directly from ubuntu packages

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and I solved by selecting "**Do not use this device**" on the control panel.
After appling and restarting it began to work fine.
By the way the name of the wireles interface has changed to something like *wlp2s0b1*

Comment: I tried this as well no success